# "At startup" vs "on startup"

Tags: word-choice

I wrote this:

> ... show **on startup** of the application.

My colleague corrects me and says it should be:

> ... show **at startup** of the application

because *at* indicates a moment in time. However, when I google it I get more results on *on*.

What's correct/better?

Comment: The application displays a [splash screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) (while starting).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*At* is commonly used to refer to specific moments in time. (In particular, while we'd use *on* for dates, we'd use *at* for times on a given date.)

*On* is commonly used to refer to events that computers react to (especially in software, but it would also cover hardware reacting to interrupts).

An application starting up is both a specific moment in time, and an event that software can react to. As such, both can be used.

I'd lean toward using *at* for the existing conditions at the time of the application starting (e.g. what environment variables are set, what other applications are running) and *on* for events which happen because of the applicaiton starting (whether planned events, or unplanned problems). However, I wouldn't consider either entirely wrong in either case.

Answer (score 4):

In the technology world, it would be more appropriate to use "on startup", because "startup" is an "event" that the computer or application is responding too, rather than a point in time.

Similar examples would be "on click" or "on blur" or "on submit" . . . you would never use "at click" or "at blur" or "at submit".

Answer (score 1):

Curiously enough I came across this question because I had just written some code using *both* ways in the same file, with different meaning for each:

[image: code capture]

The first method refers to the startup *event* of the application, so I used *"on"*, whereas the second method refers to the *moment in time* the operating system starts up, so I used *"at"*. I think this matches [Jon Hanna's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/154469/6947).